# SSL error with Python Simple-Salesforce exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, ssl-certificate, simple-salesforce

I am running a query of a Salesforce database in Python with Simple Salesforce. It works fine in the development environment, but when I compile it with py2exe and run it in a command prompt, I get an error that I understand may have to do with SSL, but don't know how to solve it. I did not include the entire code, but line 11 referred to in the error is `sf = Salesforce(username='myusername', password='mypassword', security_token='mytoken')`

I tried `sf = Salesforce(username='myusername', password='mypassword', security_token='mytoken', verify=False)` with no luck

My code:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
sf = Salesforce(username='myusername', password='mypassword', security_token='mytoken')
data = sf.query_all(select id from Case)
```

My error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfile.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "simple_salesforce\api.pyc", line 74, in __init__
  File "simple_salesforce\login.pyc", line 116, in Salesforce login
  File "requests\api.pyc", line 88, in post
  File "requests\api.pyc", line 44, in request
  File "requests\sessions.pyc", line 456, in request
  File "requests\sessions.pyc", line 559, in send
  File "requests\adapters.pyc", line 382, in send
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:344 erroroB084002:x509
certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem and fixed it by adding the Salesforce SSL Cert to the cacert.pem file on my machine. Cert is accessed from a link on Settings > Develop > API > Client Certificate.  http://na16.salesforce.com/soap/cliencert.jsp